# Soft 404's from commerce system. Redirect on page with php?

Tags: php, redirect, http-status-code-404

Our commerce system serves up an error.html inside of our template on some items that we no longer carry, and I want to put a redirect inside of the error.html to our 404.html

I can't do it inside of .htaccess because it serves the item url,and I would have to either remove a backlog of items or redirect every item. Can I do a .php redirect inside of the page?

I tried to add a .php redirect but it commented out for some reason. This:

```
<?
Header( “HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently” );
Header( “Location: https://www.asseenontvhot10.com/404.html” );
exit();
?>

<!--?
Header( “HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently” );
Header( “Location: https://www.asseenontvhot10.com/404.html” );
exit();
?-->
```

Comment: you can't. you'll run into the `headers already sent` error if you try doing a header call after output has already been performed.

Comment: The error.html that gets loaded for the page gets loaded with the main .html and other .html files and has a header section that can add information. Do you have any ideas for how to redirect this particular page? The only thing that gets loaded on this page that is different is the error.html